# Debug this code in matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, graph-theory

```
 W = [.41 .99 .51 .32 ];
 DG = sparse([4 4 2 2 ],[1 3 1 3],W); 
 view(biograph(DG,[],'ShowWeights','on'));
```

I get an error message stating the following

```
Error using ==> biograph.biograph at 155
CM must be a sparse or full square matrix

Error in ==> Untitled2 at 4
view(biograph(DG,[],'ShowWeights','on'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, `DG` is a 4x3 matrix and not a square matrix.